# How to perform following operations on Long array using java 8

Tags: java, lambda

I am exploring and learning about lambda expressions in Java. I have the following code that simple calculate the `sum` of array and return  sum

```
long[] temp = new long[n]; // assume that temp array has values
long tempVarible = 0L;
long result = 0L;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    tempVarible = tempVarible + temp[i];

    if (tempVarible > result) {
        result = tempVarible;
    }
}

return result;
```

Now i want to convert following code into a clean and single line code with lambdas, with using collection API or perhaps Arrays utility in order to calculate value of "result" variable.

```
long[] temp = new long[n];
Stream.of(temp)   // then next ..?
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this loop? Why have `result`? And why only assign `tempVarible` to it if `tempVarible > result`?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(temp).sum();`

Comment: @GBlodgett  Try imagining temp[] as Probability density function, and then result as the peak location. tempVariable is just a runner through array and its peak value will be saved in result.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use `LongStream`, if array is empty you will get `0` or else `sum`

```
return LongStream.of(temp).sum()
```

or by using `reduce`

```
long result = LongStream.of(temp).reduce((a,b)->a+b).getAsLong();
```

Comment: I want/interested in result as the final calculated value, I believe with expression you have given , I would just get the value of tempVariable at the end of the loop.

Comment: what do you mean by final calculated value? don't you need sum of long array? @NilKulkarni

Comment: No I want the lambda expression to calculate value of "result" variable. I do not want sum. i am not sure if it is even possible or not

Comment: i updated another approach by using lambda, but i'm not sure why you need that way @NilKulkarni